# How can I get a Socket ID of one user by using username?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a problem with my app chat.

For example, if I was admin of a group, I wanted to add one client to my socket room, but I couldn't know his socket ID because it's private. How can I get his socket ID? Can we be able to use his username to find his socket ID?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When a user makes a socket.io connection to your server, the server will have access to their `socket` and thus their `socket.id` at that point.  It is up to your application to be able to separately connect that incoming connection with a specific userID in your system.  Usually, that is done via a login cookie that will be present when the socket.io connection is first made to your server.

So, at that point of the inbound connection, you should be able to know the `socket`, the `socket.id` and the `userID` in your system.  It's up to you to then store that info on your server in a way (often using a Map object with userID as a key and `socket` as the value) such that you can lookup a userID and get the resulting socket.io `socket` (which also gives you access to the `socket.id`).

Upon the `disconnect` event, you would then remove the connection from the Map object.  You might also add the userID as a custom property on the `socket` object as in `socket.userID = xxx` which allows you to easily lookup the other way around (get the userID when you have the `socket`).

Comment: I create an array to store {socketID, username, userId} so when I want to add one user I pass parrameter in emit join user so server can know the socketId of user along to userId I pass in emit event and server join the user in room. Is that good ideal ?

Comment: @ĐứcPhú - Please read the detail in my answer.  I suggested a `Map` object, not an array because it's a lot more efficient to lookup a socket in than an array.

Comment: thanks for your solution, now i can handle it with Map instead of Array, so do  I need to store in redis socket io or just Map is enough.

Comment: Map is good enough unless you are clustering your servers.  Since the connection does not persist if the server restarts, you don't need this data to persist either so an in-memory data structure is fine.

Comment: because this is the first time I do project with socket io, the storage data is the problem for me, i read many post and I 
found they recommend the redis but with me it to hard to know this cache storage so thanks to solution with map i can manage socket id along userId(in mongoDb) easily.

Comment: I have one question, my  message media(video, image) must save in database so I can get the path of media file that I store in Cloudinary before emit to all user in room (emit the path from Cloudinary response) and with message text (string) I will emit immediately and after that the message will store in mongo Db opposite messenger media form (because I need the path from response ). So is there another solution for my situation ? Thanks

Comment: @ĐứcPhú - That sounds like a completely new question.  If that is something else you need help with then I'd suggest you write a new question and include all relevant code and problem description in the new question.

Comment: @ĐứcPhú - If this answer has answered your original question, then you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure which can eventually lead to earning more privileges here.